# How to set global session variables in Phalcon, values retrieved from database upon entry to the site

Tags: php, session, global, phalcon

I want to set global session variables where the values are retrieved from the database, in Phalcon upon entry to the site (ie. get site settings). What would be the best way to achieve this so this data is retrieved only once and remains in session accessible to views.

Thanks

Comment: _What would be the best way to..._ What is the status quo? Where is  your code? Post it..

Answer (score 1):

Need start the session the first time when some component request the session service.

`$di->setShared(
    "session",
    function () {
        $session = new Session();
        $session->start();
        return $session;
    }
);`

Manipulations:
1) Set a session variable

```
$this->session->set("user-name", "Michael");
```

2) Check if the variable is defined and get its value

```
if ($this->session->has("user-name")) {
   $name = $this->session->get("user-name");
}
```